# HibernateException "Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml" error while running a simple Hibernate Application

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:13)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 2 more
```

Why does this HibernateException occur?

Comment: This is a terrible title for a question. Please change it to something that describes your problem. Also, please add more information, just the stacktrace isn't much help.

Comment: ur `hibernate.cfg.xml` is non parsable. plz add ur hibernate.cfg.xml file content in the question.

Comment: Please upload your configuration fille...

Comment: This is actually 2 issues: log4j and hibernate. There is already an answer concerning hibernate but you should also "properly initialize log4j". As far as I know this warning occurs when the config files are not found and no programmatical initialization is done. Please refer to log4j documentation on how to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused because of referencing a DTD on the top of the `hibernate.cfg.xml` that is not present in the Hibernate jar you are using.

Assuming you are not using Hibernate version 2.0, check that in your hibernate.cfg.xml you have on top:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

And in case you are using XML hbm files for the entity mapping then in those XML files you have on top:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```